# how to visit the method in the child class from extends?

Tags: php, pdo, extends

Here I want to use the code **class Child_Site extends Site** to extend the class Site, and the class Site is used with the `__construct` to receive `$par1`, `$par2`. When I use
`$D=new Child_Site("ddd","gggg");$D->getTitle();` to visit his parent class, it is totally fine. But when I want to visit the child method, why it give the error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function Site::__construct(), 0 passed in
> D:\phpstudy_pro\WWW\index.php on line 39 and exactly 2 expected in
> D:\phpstudy_pro\WWW\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0
> D:\phpstudy_pro\WWW\index.php(39): Site->__construct() #1 {main}
> thrown in D:\phpstudy_pro\WWW\index.php on line 7

```
<?php
class Site {
    var $url;
    var $title;
      
    function __construct( $par1, $par2 ) {
        $this->url = $par1;
        $this->title = $par2;
    }
      
    function setUrl($par){
        $this->url = $par;
    }
        
    function getUrl(){
        echo $this->url . PHP_EOL;
    }
        
    function setTitle($par){
        $this->title = $par;
    }
        
    function getTitle(){
        echo $this->title . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Child_Site extends Site{
    var $category;

    function setCate($par){
        $this->category=$par;
    }
        
    function getCate(){
        echo $this->category.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$D = new Child_Site("ddd","gggg");
$D->getTitle();
    
$s = new Child_Site;
$s->setCate("xx");
$s->getCate();
?>
```

Comment: You are instantiating the child class twice and not passing the arguments the second time: `$s=new Child_Site;`. Did you mean to instantiate the parent class?

Comment: @Sharky I want to instantiate the child class. if I delete the parent ,I can visit child class

Comment: because there are setCate and getCate in the Child class ,so I do not need to pass arguments the second time.If it is not the case,what arguments should I pass@Sharky

Comment: When you extend a class, it inherits the same methods as the parent class, which means that if the parent constructor requires you to pass arguments when creating the class, you need to pass arguments in the child as well, which is why you get the error when you instantiate `Child_Site` without arguments.

Comment: _Side note:_ You should learn how to [define class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) the right way instead of using the old legacy way using `var`. That's from PHP 4. We're not on PHP 8.

Comment: oh thank you,your answer is clear and helpful,and also for the remainer of "define class properites" in PHP 8.It slove my confusion.@MagnusEriksson

Comment: _Correction:_ It should say "We're _now_ on PHP 8" :-) The right way of defining class properties was introduced back in PHP 5, so it's not something specific for PHP 8. That was more to point out how old the `var` keyword was.